# Stateful Rails app. Storing data not in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state, stateful

I have a Rails application, that includes chat. Everything works fine, but now I want to store the last 50 chat messages somewhere. I need it to show the last messages if a page is reloaded. I don't want to use database. It would be good to store it in some kind of array, but Rails is stateless. I'm looking to make it a little more stateful with your help.

Thx

**UPD**:

I've found `PStore` ( http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pstore/rdoc/classes/PStore.html ). It looks pretty good for me, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your simplest answer is [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html), since it is part of the Ruby core. Just dump your actual array to disk as a binary file and read it back as you need.

  ```
  MYDB = 'mydb.marshal'

  # Write to disk
  last_50 = [ "foo", "bar" ]
  File.open( MYDB, 'wb' ){ |f| f << Marshal.dump( last_50 ) }

  # Load from disk
  last_50 = Marshal.load( File.open( MYDB, 'rb' ){ |f| f.read } )
  p last_50
  #=> ["foo", "bar"]
  ```
- If you want the file format to be human-readable, try [YAML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/index.html) (part of the Ruby standard library) or [JSON](http://flori.github.com/json/) as a gem. Both are plain-text file formats that you can dump to file, see, and load again.
- You say you "don't want a database", but you don't say why. Do you know that [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) has its database in a single file, is easy to install, and is fast and lightweight?

Comment: Great answer, Phrogz. I don't want to use databse, beacause it is quite heavy. I know about sqlite and I use it often for small things. But I don't want to grab all it's functionality. I want to use something light and easy. Only thing I need is an Array or Hash with little bunch of data. File System as a storage seems to me more suitable than a databse. `PStore`, what I mentioned, uses `Marshal` as well. `YAML` and `JSON` looks very pretty too. Maybe more than `Marshal`. Thank you for remarking them. For some reason I haven't thought about them. Looks like you have answered my question :).

Comment: you may interested in this http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/pstore_meets_yaml it's PStore storing its files using YAML ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Redis](http://redis.io/)

Comment: Isn't it too huge solution for storing 50 lines of data?

Comment: It is pretty simple to run, and something you could easily find additional uses for (caching, message queue, job queue), but if it really does just remain 50 lines, then probably.